# error 91, variable not set can't use a getter

Tags: excel, vba

I can't use my `Property Get` in my main program.

I have already got this problem with the constructor of my class, I put `Set` before every property.

```
Public ID As Integer
Public numberOfError As Integer
Public error1 As Erreur
Public error2 As Erreur
Public error3 As Erreur
Public error4 As Erreur

Public Sub ajouterDTC(bid As Integer, Optional bnumberOfError As Integer, Optional berror1 As Erreur, Optional berror2 As Erreur, Optional berror3 As Erreur, Optional berror4 As Erreur)
    With Me
        .ID = bid
        .numberOfError = bnumberOfError
        Set .error1 = berror1
        Set .error2 = berror2
        Set .error3 = berror3
        Set .error4 = berror4
    End With
End Sub

'error1 properties
Public Property Get getError1() As Erreur
    getError1 = error1
End Property

Public Property Let letError1(berror1 As Erreur)
    error1 = berror1
End Property
```

Comment: `Erreur` seems to be an object, you need `Property Set`, not `Property Let` to set objects.

Comment: i agree with you and i corrected but the problem is on property get geterror. the error appear when i use geterror in the main module

Comment: `Erreur`is still an object, so you need to `Set` it. `Set getError1 = error1`.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'm very grateful. i've tried and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Erreur is still an object, so you need to `Set` it. `Set getError1 = error1`."
 by **Vincent G**